# Eclipse not publishing to Apache 6.0.32 - Could not publish to the server

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, publishing

I have been using Apache 6 with Eclipse and the Web Tools plugin for some time. Until recently, deployment usually went off without a hitch.  Now, after trying to install Apache Tomcat v6.0.32, it seems Eclipse has suddenly decided it will no longer cooperate with any version of Tomcat 6.  My Googling has been largely unfruitful.

When I attempt to publish an application to the server, this is what I get:

Severity: Error
Message: Could not publish to the server.

Exception Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.wst.web.internal.deployables.ComponentDeployable.getMembers(ComponentDeployable.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.deployables.J2EEFlexProjDeployable.addClassFolderDependencies(J2EEFlexProjDeployable.java:814)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.deployables.J2EEFlexProjDeployable.members(J2EEFlexProjDeployable.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.fillCache(ModulePublishInfo.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ModulePublishInfo.getDelta(ModulePublishInfo.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.ServerPublishInfo.getDelta(ServerPublishInfo.java:368)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.getPublishedResourceDelta(Server.java:1363)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.getPublishedResourceDelta(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:653)
    at org.eclipse.jst.server.tomcat.core.internal.TomcatServerBehaviour.getPublishedResourceDelta(TomcatServerBehaviour.java:896)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:822)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:708)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:2731)
    at org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Here's my session data:

```
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.6.0_22
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

I've had to fight with Eclipse in the past with Tomcat, but it's been a while since I've had such a catastrophic failure.  Any attempt to go to an earlier version of Tomcat 6 seems to yield the same problems. For what it's worth, here's the rest of the relevant version information on my IDE:

```
Eclipse build ID: 20100218-1602
Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools: 3.1.1.v200908101600-7_7EGrjFQRwRb4P511ebObS5XZhq
  build: 20100211202452
Eclipse Web Developer Tools: 3.1.1.v200908120400-7R77FStEVw2z07WtDz-OZrhL5C-3
  build: 20100211202452
```

One snag: This environment is standard for our team. Upgrading any components is an option only if I won't break workspace compatibility.

Comment: I feel foolish. The answer was unusual, but right in front of me if I looked.

One of the applications listed under the server to be published was also listed under a different but older server with separate runtime. Not sure how it happened (I never added it to this instance), but once I removed the app from deployment on Tomcat 6.0.32, it worked fine. I can only assume the older server runtime caused the problem.

However, adrshr is right and I shouldn't even be using this version under this version of WTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse WTP version 3.1.1 doesn't support Tomcat 6. You must upgrade, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks; I wasn't aware of that. I made the assumption that if Eclipse offered it on the generic server runtimes it was assumed to be compatible.

Comment: The latest version supports even Tomcat 7.0. I'm trying to find a link where we can download such server adapters for even older versions of Eclipse. But unfortunately, finding that link itself has been a challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same issue. I'm running MyEclipse 3.0 stable, deploying to Tomcat 8.
I was able to resolve it by removing that deployment from the server, and then adding it back in.
Hope this helps someone else that's having this problem.

Kurt